# How to flag inappropriate behaviour of a moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderation

When a user is not well behaved or when there is another issue, we have the possibility to raise flags, vote to close a question, downvote etc.

But what can the standard user do when a moderator has taken an inappropriate action or when he thinks that a moderator is biased? It seems impossible to appeal against a moderator's decision or to flag inadequate moderator behaviour. Or is there somewhere a "super-moderator" who can step in?

Just as an example, moderators can completely delete posts or comments, with a huge amount of arbitrariness. And there is ABSOLUTELY NO WAY TO BRING THEM BACK. No flags and alike.

Comment: Inappropriate, outright rude and off-topic comments are deleted without hesitation. Flags intended to bully moderators are promptly declined.

Comment: I can't understand your fuss ...

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, if you're not indicating something specific to travel, then this probably isn't a travel.SE question, and is best suited for meta.SO.

It's not impossible at all to flag moderators - I'm not sure where you get that idea. You can flag their work, email stackexchange or ask one of the other two moderators on the site to weigh in.  You can hop into the chat and @flag the other two mods and ask them for assistance.

There is also a "contact us" link at the bottom of every single page on the SE network.

If you want to air grievances publicly, you could ask it on Meta.Stackoverflow.com, but you'll need to have posts ready to cite, and reasonable grounds showing where someone has flouted the rules of the site, been unnecessarily offensive/wrong/whatever other reason you feel is valid for being considered 'inappropriate.

Finally, you could...I don't know, consider communicating with the moderator, explaining why you feel they've been inappropriate, and see if you can resolve it like reasonable people.

Other similar questions you may find of interest:

- [What is the process of removing a moderator from office if he/she goes rogue?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/946/what-is-the-process-of-removing-a-moderator-from-office-if-he-she-goes-rogue)
- [Handling calls to remove a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151606/handling-calls-to-remove-a-moderator)
- [What can be done for rogue moderators (Moderators that go bad)](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6036/what-can-be-done-for-rogue-moderators-moderators-that-go-bad)

I don't think we have a problem on Travel.SE, but I figured you may find the links interesting, regardless of whether one thinks there is or isn't a problem here.

Comment: The question is on topic. We have already had a similar debate. See for instance the comment made by shog9: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/1421/3470

Comment: "I'm not sure where you get that idea" Do you really think that moderators are beyond reproach? It seems so. I can understand, you have been one of them. However, I tend to believe that they make mistakes, are biased, etc just as any human being. That's why I am asking

Comment: @MarcelC. by "I'm not sure where you get that idea" - I was merely referring to the part where you said "it seems impossible to to appeal against a moderator's decision".  At no point have I said they're beyond reproach, and indeed I wrote an entire answer above about how you can take an action against one if you think they've done something wrong.  I don't understand after I wrote all that above, how you can possibly come up with "do you really think that moderators are beyond reproach".

Comment: Any grievances with the moderators on a specific site are best raised on that site's meta, not MSO.

Comment: @AnnaLear indeed. As the question was how to flag them in general, it sounded more like a process thing.  However his other question and posts on meta would now certainly seem to indicate he has a grievance on Travel, with one mod in particular.  (that's my understanding of it, at least)